# How to make Wordpress Custom Post Type Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

[image: This is simple picture]

> [Permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)
>
> [Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)
>
> [Register Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

I'll be using this permalinks settings `(e.g. /%second%%minute%%hour%%day%)`

Now deafult post link > `www."mywebsite".com/12331406`

I have a `post_type` simple: **onur**

onur's posts working with this permalink > `www."mywebsite".com/onur/post-title`

But I need > `www."mywebsite".com/12331406` or/else > `www."mywebsite".com/onur/12331406` not problem.

Any help...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like this what you want but i don't know whether this will work for you or not

just add this in **functions.php** file

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'woorei_33551_custom_listing_permalink', 1, 3);

function woorei_33551_custom_listing_permalink($post_link, $post = 0, $leavename) {

    if ( $post->post_type == 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' ) {
        //You can whatever you want to instead of post id
        return home_url( '/' . $post->ID);

    }

    else {

        return $post_link;

    }

}

add_action( 'init', 'woorei_33551_rewrites_init' );

function woorei_33551_rewrites_init(){

    add_rewrite_rule(

        '([0-9]+)?$',

        'index.php?post_type=CUSTOM_POST_TYPE&p=$matches[1]',

        'top' );

}
```

Comment: I'll test. Thank you @Jivani-Jaydeep